# UITableViewCell duplicates values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I'm using Firebase and outer API to fetch data for UITableView.
Generally I have this code.

```
public static func getUserLayers(completion: @escaping ()->Void){
    Firestore.firestore().collection("layers").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.layers.removeAll()
            if let snap = snapshot?.documents {
                for doc in snap {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    let provider = data["layerprovider"] as! Int
                    if(provider != 0){
                        Alamofire.request("\(self.providerBaseUrl)\(String(describing: provider))").responseString { (response) in
                            if let resp = response.value {
                                let json = JSON(parseJSON: resp)
                                let logo = json["logo"]["medium"]["url"]
                                let blue = json["bg"]["blue"].intValue
                                let green = json["bg"]["green"].intValue
                                let red = json["bg"]["red"].intValue
                                self.layers.append(
                                    LayerInfo(ean: data["ean"] as! String, name: String(describing: data["name"]), logo: Provider.getLogo(imageUrl: "\(logo)"), bgR: red, bgG: green, bgB: blue, provider: json)
                                )
                            }
                            completion()
                        }

                    }else{
                        self.layers.append(
                            LayerInfo(ean: data["ean"] as! String, name: String(describing: data["name"]), logo: UIImage(), bgR: 0, bgG: 0, bgB: 0)
                        )
                    }
                }
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's the code that fetches data from Firebase, and then trying to fetch provider if it's not equals to '0'.

ViewController here is:

```
LayerService.getUserLayers {
            self.layers = LayerService.layers
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

And the UITableViewCell:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for subview in self.subviews{
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let layer = Layer(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: self.bounds.width - 40, height: 210), bg: self.bg, logo: self.logo, ean: self.ean)
        self.addSubview(layer)
    }
```

But the problem is that during reusing cells - it's duplicates 1st and 5th cells, 2nd and 6th cells, etc.
And even when I click the cell #1 it flips layer at cell #5(since I have flip on tap at Layer UIView subclass)...

Where could I be wrong?

Thanks. Any suggestions appreciated.

**My `cellForRowAt` method**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! LayersTableViewCell 
    cell.logo = self.layers[indexPath.row].logo 
    cell.bg = self.layers[indexPath.row].bg 
    cell.ean = self.layers[indexPath.row].ean 
    return cell 
}
```

Comment: Please show your func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell method

Comment: @Andrey Chernukha `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! LayersTableViewCell
        
        cell.logo = self.layers[indexPath.row].logo
        cell.bg = self.layers[indexPath.row].bg
        cell.ean = self.layers[indexPath.row].ean
        
        return cell
    }`

Answer (score 0):

please reload your table view after parse the data

```
public static func getUserLayers(completion: @escaping (AnyObject)->Void){
Firestore.firestore().collection("layers").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.layers.removeAll()
            if let snap = snapshot?.documents {
                for doc in snap {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    let provider = data["layerprovider"] as! Int
                    if(provider != 0){
                        Alamofire.request("\(self.providerBaseUrl)\(String(describing: provider))").responseString { (response) in
                            if let resp = response.value {
                                let json = JSON(parseJSON: resp)
                                let logo = json["logo"]["medium"]["url"]
                                let blue = json["bg"]["blue"].intValue
                                let green = json["bg"]["green"].intValue
                                let red = json["bg"]["red"].intValue
                                self.layers.append(
                                    LayerInfo(ean: data["ean"] as! String, name: String(describing: data["name"]), logo: Provider.getLogo(imageUrl: "\(logo)"), bgR: red, bgG: green, bgB: blue, provider: json)
                                )
                            }
                            completion(["res": self.layers, "stats":1] as AnyObject?)
                        }

                    }else{
                        self.layers.append(
                            LayerInfo(ean: data["ean"] as! String, name: String(describing: data["name"]), logo: UIImage(), bgR: 0, bgG: 0, bgB: 0)
                        )
                    }
                }
                completion(["res": self.layers, "stats":1] as AnyObject?)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then modify :

```
LayerService.getUserLayers (withCompletionHandler:AnyObject?) in{
        let dictResponse = withCompletionHandler as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            let isSuccess : Int = dictResponse["stats"] as! Int

            if isSuccess == 1{
              self.layers = LayerService.layers
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
              }
            }

    }
```

It may helps you.Thank you.

Comment: That could be problematical, cuz:
1) I have Alamofire.request not in a view, where tableView is located.
2) R U sure that when I fetch 100 items for tableView - I need to reloadData() after each item?

Thanks.

Comment: No. After add all the data in array you reload the table view.

Comment: Modified your answer a bit, cuz completion handler was a bit messy, but I think I got the main idea you wanted to show me. Unfortunately UITableView acts the same after changes :(

Comment: One more thing that could probably help - when I'm using simple textLabel at each UITableViewCell that shows just name from received data instead of complex sublayer(with 2 more sublayers inside) it acts perfectly! So it looks more like some kind of caching of smth like that for me and not dispatch order.